# Selecting a subset of a big SpatialPolygonsDataFrame using a masking vector

Tags: r, r-s4, r-sp

Can anyone help me understand why this doesn't work how I think it should?

I have a 1,000+ element `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` object (i.e. from `sp`) and I'd like to cut it down to a vector of 20 random items from the whole.

```
n <- dim(geo1) # where geo1 is a big SpatialPolygonsDataFrame object
n <-n [1]
set.seed(1) # set random number generator seed for repeatability.
new_n=20    # Choose 20 random polygons
mask <- sample(0:n,new_n,replace=F) # trim size down from n to new_n polygons.
geo1small <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(Sr = geo1@polygons[mask], data = geo1@data[mask,], match.ID = TRUE)
```

Result:

```
Error in SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(Sr = geo1@polygons[mask], data = geo1@data[mask,  : 
trying to get slot "polygons" from an object of a basic class ("list") with no slots
```

Comment: You can directly subset the object by index: `geo1small <- geo1[mask, ]`

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to mark your comment as the right "answer," and I realize my question as asked is unlikely to be much help to others. Not sure if I handled the answer below appropriately; please advise if I ought to change anything. Thanks again.

Comment: If this answer your question, you can mark my answer below as [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 2):

You can directly subset spatial objects by index:

```
geo1small <- geo1[mask, ]
```